# How do I run a comparison using only one class twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `model`:

```
public class Parameter
{
    [Key]
    public int paramID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "No.")]
    public int paramNo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string parameter { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Meaning")]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Synonym")]
    public string synonym { get; set; }
    public int catID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CompareParameter> CompareParameters { get; set; }
}
```

I need to add a model that compares all objects in the Parameter with each of the other objects in Parameter.  So far I have this:

```
public class CompareParameter
{
    [Key]
    public int CompareID { get; set; }
    public int paramID1 { get; set; }
    public int paramID2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Parameter Parameters { get; set; }
    public virtual Parameter Parameters2 { get; set; }
}
```

Where `paramID1` takes the key from Parameter and `paramID2` does the same.  Only it does not appear to be working at the moment.

Any ideas?

**=== Update Question ===**

With the two models I have given as examples, what should I do about `CompareParameter` to allow me to build a controller and a view that will have two dropdowns of the same class.  The purpose of this is so that I can link it to another class with possible outcomes.

Comment: Sorry, but what is MatrixParameter?

Comment: Your code appears incomplete to answer this question. Are you saying you want to compare the values of each field in the Parameter class with the same fields in another instance of a Parameter class, or a collection of Parameter classes?

Comment: Hi, IntoNET. I am going to build another model that attaches to the CompareParameter class. All I want at the moment is that each CompareID allows for two instances of the Parameter class.

Comment: Why don't you derive your Parameter class from Comparer<T> and implement the comparison that way?

Comment: I will look into that. I was not aware of a Comparer<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should derive your Parameter class from Comparer and implement the comparison that way.

Comment: I have checked with Comparer and although that runs the comparison well for most things, it will not work on this project.  Currently I just need 'CompareParameter' to allow me to build a controller and a view of two dropdowns, displaying the title of the 'Parameter' class.

Comment: Unless you have an example that demonstrates this.

Comment: Your question is really too vague/incomplete to be able to provide an acceptable answer.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect what I need. I hope this does not allow further confusion in what is required.